# Given that the customer has filed a claim, what is the probability that the customer is a good risk

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An automobile insurance company divides customers into three categories, good
risks, medium risks, and poor risks. Assume that 70% of the customers are good
risks, 20% are medium risks, and 10% are poor risks. Assume that during the
course of a year, a good risk customer has probability 0.005 of filing an accident claim, a medium risk customer has probability 0.01, and a poor risk customer has probability 0.025. A customer is chosen at random.

Given that the customer has filed a claim, what is the probability that the
 customer is a good risk?

I think the total probability that the customer has filed a claim is (0.7*0.005+0.2*0.01+0.1*0.025)
So the probability that the customer is a good risk is (0.7*0.005)/(0.7*0.005+0.2*0.01+0.1*0.025).

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, this is a direct application of Bayes' theorem. You just need to finish the math:

$$\begin{split}
P(Good|Claim) &= \frac{P(Good \cap Claim)}{P(Claim)} \\
&= \frac{0.7 \cdot 0.005}{0.7 \cdot 0.005 + 0.2 \cdot 0.01 + 0.1 \cdot 0.025} \\
&= \frac{0.0035}{0.008} \\
&= 0.4375
\end{split}$$

Answer (score 0):

We note that we can apply [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) here:

$$P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(B \mid A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

So in our problem, we wish to find:

$$P(\text{good} \mid \text{claimed})=\frac{P(\text{claimed} \mid \text{good})P(\text{good})}{P(\text{claimed})}$$

So we note that the question gives us two of these quantities right from the start. We have: $P(\text{claimed}\mid \text{good})= 0.005$ and $P(\text{good})= 0.7$. We can now calculate the probability that a claim is made:

$$P(\text{claimed}) = 0.7\times 0.005 + 0.2\times 0.01 + 0.1 \times 0.025 = 0.008$$

Thus:

$$P(\text{good}\mid \text{claimed})=\frac{0.005 \times 0.7}{0.008} = 0.4375$$